# Modifying Turtlebot3 to include different camera

Tags: ros, gazebo, c++

I'm new to robotics in ROS. I've been learning about ROS and Gazebo using turtlebot (not turtlebot3 actually) on the platform [The Construct](https://www.theconstructsim.com/). I would now like to incorporate turtlebot3 into my project.

I'm trying to build a robot which uses turtlebot3 burger as a base with the LDS (Laser Distance Sensor) removed (check out the original turtlebot3 burger spec [here](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/features/#worlds-most-popular-ros-platform)) and replaced with an [Intel D435i camera](https://www.intelrealsense.com/depth-camera-d435i/). I would like to retain all the other aspects of the robot (dynamics, topics, nodes etc).

I have already installed the `IntelRealSense/realsense-ros` package from [github](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros) as well as the `ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3` from [here](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3).
I have looked at [this webpage](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_model&cat=build_robot) on the Gazebo website, and it seems I need to modify the SDF model of the Turtlebot and somehow incorporate the correct links and joints to get the camera working correctly.

I don't know where to start with editing the turtlebot to include this camera.

Answer (score 1):

You can start editing with urdf file. Edit the file `catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_burger.gazebo.xacro`.
remove the following part.

```xml
  <gazebo reference="base_scan">
    <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
    <sensor type="ray" name="lds_lfcd_sensor">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>$(arg laser_visual)</visualize>
      <update_rate>5</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>360</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>0.0</min_angle>
            <max_angle>6.28319</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.120</min>
          <max>3.5</max>
          <resolution>0.015</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.01</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="gazebo_ros_lds_lfcd_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
        <topicName>scan</topicName>
        <frameName>base_scan</frameName>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
```

and add your sensor.
You will need to adjust the `sensor_link` name and also change it in the `joints`.
In the file `catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_burger.urdf.xacro` replace the following with your appropriate sensor name.

```xml
  <joint name="scan_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="base_scan"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.032 0 0.172" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="base_scan">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://turtlebot3_description/meshes/sensors/lds.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="dark"/>
    </visual>

    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0.015 0 -0.0065" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.0315" radius="0.055"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>

    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.114" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
      <inertia ixx="0.001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
               iyy="0.001" iyz="0.0"
               izz="0.001" />
    </inertial>
  </link>
```

or use the same names in your new sensor.
For reference this is the d435 sensor plugin I use.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sdf version="1.5">
   <model name="d435">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <link name="base_link">
         <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
         <inertial>
            <pose>0 0.0175 0.0125 0 -0 0</pose>
            <mass>0.564</mass>
            <inertia>
               <ixx>0.00388124</ixx>
               <ixy>0</ixy>
               <ixz>0</ixz>
               <iyy>0.00049894</iyy>
               <iyz>0</iyz>
               <izz>0.00387926</izz>
            </inertia>
         </inertial>
         <collision name="collision">
            <pose>0 0 0.0125 0 -0 0</pose>
            <geometry>
               <box>
                  <size>0.025 0.09 0.025</size>
               </box>
            </geometry>
            <surface>
               <contact>
                  <ode>
                     <kp>1e+13</kp>
                     <kd>1</kd>
                  </ode>
               </contact>
               <friction>
                  <ode>
                     <mu2>1</mu2>
                     <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
                  </ode>
               </friction>
            </surface>
         </collision>
         <visual name="visual">
            <pose>0 0 0.0125 1.5708 -0 1.5708</pose>
            <geometry>
               <mesh>
                  <uri>model://d435/meshes/d435.dae</uri>
               </mesh>
            </geometry>
            <material>
               <ambient>0.5 0.5 0.5 1</ambient>
               <diffuse>0.9 0.9 0.9 0.5</diffuse>
               <specular>0.1 0.1 0.1 1</specular>
               <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
               <shader type="pixel">
                  <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
               </shader>
               <lighting>1</lighting>
            </material>
            <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
         </visual>
         <sensor name="cameracolor" type="camera">
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <camera name="camera">
               <horizontal_fov>1.500</horizontal_fov>
               <image>
                  <width>640</width>
                  <height>360</height>
                  <format>RGB_INT8</format>
               </image>
               <clip>
                  <near>0.1</near>
                  <far>30</far>
               </clip>
               <noise>
                  <type>gaussian</type>
                  <mean>0</mean>
                  <stddev>0.0</stddev>
               </noise>
            </camera>
            <always_on>1</always_on>
            <update_rate>30</update_rate>
            <visualize>0</visualize>
         </sensor>
         <sensor name="cameraired1" type="camera">
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <camera name="camera">
               <horizontal_fov>1.500</horizontal_fov>
               <image>
                  <width>640</width>
                  <height>360</height>
                  <format>L_INT8</format>
               </image>
               <clip>
                  <near>0.1</near>
                  <far>30</far>
               </clip>
               <noise>
                  <type>gaussian</type>
                  <mean>0</mean>
                  <stddev>0.0</stddev>
               </noise>
            </camera>
            <always_on>1</always_on>
            <update_rate>30</update_rate>
            <visualize>0</visualize>
            <pose>0 0.0175 0.0125 0 -0 0</pose>
         </sensor>
         <sensor name="cameraired2" type="camera">
            <pose>0 0.05 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <camera name="camera">
               <horizontal_fov>1.500</horizontal_fov>
               <image>
                  <width>640</width>
                  <height>360</height>
                  <format>L_INT8</format>
               </image>
               <clip>
                  <near>0.1</near>
                  <far>30</far>
               </clip>
               <noise>
                  <type>gaussian</type>
                  <mean>0</mean>
                  <stddev>0.0</stddev>
               </noise>
            </camera>
            <always_on>1</always_on>
            <update_rate>30</update_rate>
            <visualize>0</visualize>
         </sensor>
         <sensor name="cameradepth" type="depth">
            <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
            <camera name="camera">
               <horizontal_fov>1.48702</horizontal_fov>
               <image>
                  <width>640</width>
                  <height>360</height>
               </image>
               <clip>
                  <near>0.1</near>
                  <far>20</far>
               </clip>
               <noise>
                  <type>gaussian</type>
                  <mean>0</mean>
                  <stddev>0.0</stddev>
               </noise>
            </camera>
            <always_on>1</always_on>
            <update_rate>30</update_rate>
            <visualize>0</visualize>
         </sensor>
      </link>
      <plugin name="camera" filename="librealsense_gazebo_plugin.so">
         <prefix>camera</prefix>
         <depthUpdateRate>30.0</depthUpdateRate>
         <colorUpdateRate>30.0</colorUpdateRate>
         <infraredUpdateRate>30.0</infraredUpdateRate>
         <depthTopicName>depth_aligned_to_color_and_infra1/image_raw</depthTopicName>
         <depthCameraInfoTopicName>depth/camera_info</depthCameraInfoTopicName>
         <colorTopicName>color/image_raw</colorTopicName>
         <colorCameraInfoTopicName>color/camera_info</colorCameraInfoTopicName>
         <infrared1TopicName>infra1/image_raw</infrared1TopicName>
         <infrared1CameraInfoTopicName>infra1/camera_info</infrared1CameraInfoTopicName>
         <infrared2TopicName>infra2/image_raw</infrared2TopicName>
         <infrared2CameraInfoTopicName>infra2/camera_info</infrared2CameraInfoTopicName>
         <colorOpticalframeName>camera_color_optical_frame</colorOpticalframeName>
         <depthOpticalframeName>camera_depth_optical_frame</depthOpticalframeName>
         <infrared1OpticalframeName>camera_left_ir_optical_frame</infrared1OpticalframeName>
         <infrared2OpticalframeName>camera_right_ir_optical_frame</infrared2OpticalframeName>
         <rangeMinDepth>0.01</rangeMinDepth>
         <rangeMaxDepth>20.0</rangeMaxDepth>
         <pointCloud>1</pointCloud>
         <pointCloudTopicName>depth/color/points</pointCloudTopicName>
         <pointCloudCutoff>0.01</pointCloudCutoff>
         <pointCloudCutoffMax>20.0</pointCloudCutoffMax>
      </plugin>
   </model>
</sdf>
```

You can adjust the topics you need. Hope this helps.